# Retrieve names of function parameters in JavaScript

Tags: function, javascript

I have a JavaScript function which accepts a function as a parameter, like this:

```
var myFunction = function(funParameter) {
    // funParameter is a function
};
```

I can call this function like this:

```
myFunction(function (aParameter, anotherOne) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Inside the body of `myFunction`, how can I retrieve the parameters that `funParameter` is supposed to receive? I want to know the parameters declared with the function passed to `myFunction` (in the above case, I want to know the the parameter function accepts `aParameter` and `anotherOne`.

Only way I know of doing this is by parsing appropriately `funParameter.toString()`, but I feel like it's kind of hacky.

It should be like in Mocha tests:

```
it('should test something synchronously', function () {...});
it('should test something asynchronously', function (done) {
    // test...
    done();
});
```

You have to be able to behave differently if the function you pass to `it` accepts a `done` parameter or not.

Comment: I think you're stuck with `toString`... AFAIK no there's no other way .

Comment: I'm intrigued by the question (so +1), but I look at it and can't help but think (along the lines of) "good grief, what on earth are you doing, and *why*?"

Comment: @DavidThomas :) That's ok, it's quite uncomfortable for me too. But hey, look at the `it` function from the Mocha test suit: how the hell do they do that?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Unless the parameter names are guaranteed to be consistent throughout the code and will never be tempered by any means, you do not want to check if the parameter is named, 'done', Most of cases, developers should be free to name their function parameters.

Besides, javascript code (for browser) is usually uglified and mangled, and parameter names are shortened. If the names are changed, it is going to break your function.

However, what you rather want to do is to decide how many parameters are specified by the function and that can be done by `Function.length`.

Yet, this is not a reliable solution either, because you can always not specify anything and still get the parameter values using `arguments`.

In JavaScript, it is usually bad idea to assume that something will work in the way I intended. Because you never know who's going to do what with their codes.

The language itself is so dynamic in so many ways, you have to be really careful before designing your functions / API.

from MDN:

```
console.log( (function () {}).length );  /* 0 */
console.log( (function (a) {}).length ); /* 1 */
console.log( (function (a, b) {}).length ); /* 2 etc. */
console.log( (function (...args) {}).length ); /* 0, rest parameter is not counted */
```

Comment: This is a way to solve the problem, but you could need the named parameters, like in AngularJS (as mentioned in previous answers).

Comment: "You do not want to check if the parameter is named 'done'"-- Well, it all depends on what you're trying to do. AngularJS does something like what OP is asking for dependency injection. The number of parameters and the order is trivial, what matters is the name. Another example is John Resig's tmpl used `toString` on function to find the `super` class.

Comment: It is not a reliable solution. what if the code is uglified and parameter names are changed?

Comment: But if that's the requirement of the question, it makes it a *necessary* part of the answer.

Comment: @Juno I know it doesn't, but it shows you a way it could be used. For most cases `Function.length` is better though.

Comment: Well, that's one of the cons, yes. Angular works around it passing an array of strings first. I'm not saying is the best solution, just saying that the length is not always what's important, and stringifying functions has its place.

Comment: @David Really? So you should not give any more information than what is asked?

Comment: Perhaps I phrased that badly; I meant to say that if the OP has a situation in which the name of the parameter is important (and without further information as to *why*, it becomes difficult to argue against the need), then I tend to believe that it's necessary. By all means offer an argument against the need, or the use, or suggest alternatives; but to declare *You do not want to check if the parameter is named, 'done'* is a little presumptuous (and your argument against doesn't really carry significant weight, albeit 'imho' and so forth).

Comment: Btw, it was John Resig's class inheritance script that uses `toString` not tmpl. There's a breakdown of this script here http://blog.buymeasoda.com/understanding-john-resigs-simple-javascript-i/; you can see it has real value for maybe 1% of cases.

Comment: I'm going to say that John Resig's solution to search for _super is hacky and not a reliable solution.

Comment: Again, "John Resig did it" does not make it right. I respect John Resig and what he has done, but the solution he presented should not be used in libraries for browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for specifically how Mocha does it, look at the [source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha).

I dug into a bit and found that Mocha is simply checking the length property of the passed function as you see in this [source file](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/runnable.js). They then do an if check for the async property, shown below. If async is true, it calls the test function in a different way to handle the async nature of the test function.

```
this.async = fn && fn.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting function parameters by `Function.prototype.toString` is hacky indeed. So far, despite not being in the specs, it is very well supported by all browsers I have tested, and is used by AngularJS to map requested controller capabilities by unordered parameter name.

```
function myFunction(func) {
    var params = func.toString()
        .match(/function\s*.*\((.+)\)/)[1]
        .split(',');

    return params;  // ['aParameter', 'anotherOne']
}
```

*source modeified from ['functools'](https://github.com/1337/js-modules-bundle/blob/master/functools.js#L24)

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that. Anyway, your function is kind of buggy if the function has no parameters or spaced parameters? This should be better: `function pars(fun) { return fun.toString.match(/function.*?\((.*?)\)/)[1].split(',').map(function (el) { return el.trim(); }) }`

Comment: Wow, it doesn't look that good in a comment. I'll edit your answer.